# How to create element with id name using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to create element with id name using javascript ?

I want to create `<span id="inner">xxx</span>` inner `<div id="outter">`

I tried , but i cannot add `id="inner"` to `<span>`

http://jsfiddle.net/rndao3rd/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>

        <div id="outer">
        </div>

        <script>
            var para = document.createElement("span");
            var node = document.createTextNode("xxx");
            para.appendChild(node);
            var element = document.getElementById("outer");
            element.appendChild(para);
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript second line add this code:

```
para.id = "inner";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it this way:

```
para.setAttribute("id", "inner");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add id using two ways :

1) 
**para.id="Id";**
2)
**para.setAttribute("id","Id");**